# How can I have conditional ion-back-button text based on if the defaultHref is used?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a button that I want to display text but only when the defaultHref is used. Is there a way to detect that?

```
<ion-back-button *ngIf="defaultHref" [defaultHref]="defaultHref" [text]="text" icon="ios-arrow-back" mode="md"></ion-back-button>
```

If the back button shows as a result of a different router forward, the back button link goes somewhere else but the text I set is still there. Is there a way to make that text conditional upon the link matching the defaultHref that I set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From some investigation, [the component itself doesn't know](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/core/src/components/back-button/back-button.tsx) if it can go back until it tries to go back:

```
  private onClick = async (ev: Event) => {
    const nav = this.el.closest('ion-nav');
    ev.preventDefault();

    if (nav && await nav.canGoBack()) {
      return nav.pop({ skipIfBusy: true });
    }
    return openURL(this.defaultHref, ev, 'back');
  }
```

This is still possible though because you can just mimic this, and check if the app can go back in the logic that you use to set the text.

Page.html:

```
<ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-back-button defaultHref="/custom-back-button" [text]="getCustomText()"></ion-back-button>
</ion-buttons>
```

Page.ts:

```
  constructor(
    private ionRouterOutlet: IonRouterOutlet
  ) { }

  getCustomText():string {
    if(this.ionRouterOutlet.canGoBack()) {
      return "Can Go Back Text";
    } else {
      return "Can Only Go To Default";
    }
  }
```

Which shows this when it's navigated directly:

[image]

And this when it has a history to go back to:

[image]

Comment: I think you may have found it though, it would be nav.canGoBack(), right?

Comment: The snippet with `nav.canGoBack()` is written platform-independent with tsx / StencilJS so it's a bit different. If you look in the main code sample we inject an `IonRouterOutlet` in the constructor. This manages the router in Angular so we can get to the same functionality. There is an `ion-nav` but it wasn't clear to me when it's appropriate to use this so I went with what worked :)