# How to change the label of back button in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4, angular8

Given a multi language Ionic 4 application.
User can select the language.

How can I change (or more like), how can the text set to be dynamic ?

This is how far I got - but of course this isn't working:

```
<ion-back-button [text]="{{ app.button.back | translate }}"></ion-back-button>
```

**UPDATE:**
I meant by not working, I get the following error:

```
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at 
column 0 in [{{ app.button.back | translate }}]
```

Comment: It helps to explain what you mean by "isnt working".

Comment: I thought that I had [answered this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56999235/how-can-i-have-conditional-ion-back-button-text-based-on-if-the-defaulthref-is-u/56999929#56999929), but it seems it was a different problem - however it does show how to customise the back button text, so the issue is somewhere with the translate. Does `app.button.back` have a value?

Comment: @rtpHarry - yes, I should have added the error : Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at 
column 0 in [{{ app.button.back | translate }}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining two features here:

```
[text]="{{ app.button.back | translate }}"
```

You just need to remove the `[]` so its not expecting a javascript value:

```
<ion-back-button text="{{ 'app.button.back' | translate }}"></ion-back-button>
```

Comment: It looks like it tries to access the app object : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'button' of undefined, on the same page this works : <ion-text color="primary">{{ 'app.label.average' | translate }}</ion-text>

Comment: I got it, the right syntax is : <ion-back-button text="{{ 'app.button.back' | translate }}"></ion-back-button> , Would you edit your answer and I will accept it, as it lead me to the solution

Comment: I've tweaked it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method in ionic 4:

```
 <ion-back-button [defaultHref]="defaultHref" slot="start" text="{{ 'SIGNUP.BACK' | translate }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

In ionic 6 you can use a small hack:

```
const Ionic = (window as any as IonicWindow).Ionic;
(Ionic.config as Map<string, string>).set("backButtonText","MyBackText");
```